# Matching ranges of products versions to attributes

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I'm looking at moving some product specs into a database.  Currently they are implemented in a text file in a sort of home-brewed XML.  For instance if our product was socks, and we wanted to track the color through versions of that sock, it would look something like:

```
<SOCK ID>
  <COLOR>
      <VERSIONS>
        <LOW_000_HIGH_103  "Yellow">
        <LOW_114_HIGH_999  "Blue">
      </VERSIONS>
    </COLOR>
</SOCK ID>
```

Specs tend to be fairly stable, so there are long ranges of versions without change.  So my question is how to best represent this is a data schema.

My thought is to create a table for the unique specs, and then a secondary many-to-one table matches each product ID and version # to the appropriate spec.  Of course it would be nice if it matched a product and a *range* to spec, is that possible in SQL, or is there another schema that is better?

Edit: I found [this](http://www.dbforums.com/database-concepts-design/532204-database-design-range-data.html) solution which recommends a specified beginning and end range value as fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have products and each product has versions and each version may have some attributes in it.

I think your approach is fine. Simply store all the data you can in various relationships.

SQL is very flexible and you can get quite creative with it. I would start by simply storing the data in a way that is intuitive for you to think about. When you need to do range queries, you might have to think a bit how to write the query, but it's possible.

Keep in mind you can do things like pivoting in SQL (turning rows into columns) or grouping or even putting data into temporary tables in memory to help slowly form the data into something that resembles what you want.